# How do I know how long a user or a single IP address spent on a page of my site?

Tags: javascript, php, time, dom-events

How do I know how long a user or a single [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) spent on a page of my site?
Can I use any event of [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)?

Answer (score 5):

This is what [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) is for. It keeps track of visitors to your website and reports statistics to you like such as length of visit. They even [offer an API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/) to help you get this information.

Comment: You might want to expand a bit. While it answer, it reads more like a comment.

Comment: foremost, its not an answer at all.

Answer (score 0):

**To implement inside your application**

- When a user loads a page, their "last page load time" is updated in the database.
- A cron script runs every minute. It looks for users whose "last page load time" was in the last minute.
- Increment the "time spent on site" for each user found.

In this way, I can keep track of users accurately to the minute. Just divide by 60 to get the hours.

**Else**

[Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/). You can check out it's features [here](http://www.google.com/analytics/features/index.html).

Comment: What happens when a user closes the browser? Do you assume they're still viewing a page? How do you distinguish the difference?

Comment: cron job will take care of it. it runs every min. it checks whether user is in the system. when user is not in the system you can update the time as he left.

Comment: If a user is just looking at a page for a long time (more than a minute), how do you know they're doing that? If the page is loaded there's no way to tell how long they viewed the last page for before they left?

Comment: that's why we updated the database every one min using cron job. It keeps track of everything.

Comment: You can't look in the browser from the server side, so you don't know if the page is still shown.

Answer (score 0):

I will go for a [Redis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redis_%28data_store%29) installation that keeps tracks of a specific hash created by a combination of [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address), USERAGENT and login information (if you have it).

Save the stuff in Redis with a timestamp (use hashes or whatever you like) and then add a "farewell" timestamp when the user logs out or leaves the site for an external link or unloads the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax to send keep-alive information to your backend. Save it as session data in your database.

The session data can save the current page the user is watching and was active last time. Send the keep-alive information using, for example, `setInterval` every x seconds (depending on resolution needs).

There is no need for [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)...